# R: Difference between glm and gls

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, model, linear

What are the differences between glm and gls in r?

How do I choose which one to use for any set of data?

I tried googling but nothing gives, are they the same thing in R?
I know the other is general least squares and the other general linear model.

Comment: And do you know what the terms ["general\[ized\] least squares"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) and ["general\[ized\] linear model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) mean?

Comment: @Roland, there are indeed two different linear models – general and generalized – but I am not aware of general LS, only generalized LS.

Comment: @RichardHardy I'm quoting OP and marking my modifications. `glm` and `gls` are implementations of Generalized Linear Models and Generalized Least Squares, resp.

Comment: @Roland, OK, I just found your use of the term "general[...] least squares" a little misleading in the sense that it might not exist. Even if it was OP who used it first, it does not mean it should be repeated without a warning. But now we have clarified this, so that's alright.